# How to set a timer for Servicetimer.interval set to every 15th day and the last day of the month c#

Tags: c#, .net

Here is the code: Need to modify this to run the service every 15th day and last day of every month

```
this.serviceTimer.Interval = 300000;      // 5 mins
this.serviceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler  (this.serviceTimer_Click);
this.serviceTimer.Start();
Logger.WriteEventLog("Service Started");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just small Business logic to be done as shown below :

Set time interval for every 24 hours
timer.Interval = 60000*60*24;
Then check for current month and get number of days in current month so you will get total number of days then divide total number of days by 2 so that you have 2 dates 
1) last day of month ie total no of days in month 
2) middle date of month ie divided by 2 
check for current date with these 2 days if it is equal then go for **timeElapsed event**

```
{      
        this.serviceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler     (this.serviceTimer_Click);

}

else 
{

 do nothing

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your serviceTimer_Click

```
{
   ...
   DateTime nextExecute = DateTime.Now.AddMOnth(1);
   timer.Stop();
   timer.Interval = (nextExecute - DatTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
   timer.Start();
}
```

And to start it:

```
{
  ...
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

  DateTime firstExecute = new DateTime( now.Year, now.Month, 15 ); //add time if needed...

  if ( firstExecute < now )
  {
     firstExecute.AddMonth( 1 );
  }
  timer.Interval = (firstExecute - now).TotalMilliseconds;

}
```

Not compiled, but you get the drift...

**Edit**

Speaking about drift: to avoid your execution drifting to a later point in time, you could use a more clever way to build the nextExecute DateTime.